# Use of "remain pending"

Tags: sentence

Can I say: hello, remain pending the approval from your side of the budget, I send you yesterday and did not have a response.

Comment: You mean as in "The hearse didn't make it here in time for the funeral; remains pending"??

Comment: It's more like: "Remain pending of approval from your side....I'm not sure that remains pending sounds good at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Why don't you put an example of what you want to say **in the question**???

Comment: Ok, here you go my friend: hello, remain pending the approval from your side of the budget, I send you yesterday and did not have a response.

Comment: You should edit that into your question (since you failed to put it there when you created the question in the first place).

Comment: I make the change already

Comment: You can say that, but will not create any great impressions doing so.  "Remain pending" is two words, not one.  "Pending" is an adjective (look it up).

Comment: And how did you send your guy yesterday, by limousine?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If "remain pending the approval from your side of the budget" is supposed to be a sentence, it has no predicate.

Comment: "I send you yesterday" means that you somehow caused the person ("you") to be sent yesterday.  (Except that it's the wrong tense, of course -- should be "sent".)

Comment: If i say: "we send few emails but we did not have response. " is ok?

Comment: "We sent a few emails but we did not receive any response."

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot say: "hello, remain pending the approval from your side of the budget, I send you yesterday and did not have a response". This makes no sense!

It would make more sense if you structured the sentence entirely different.

**EXAMPLE**: Hello, since I did not receive a response from you yesterday, the approval from your part of the budget remains pending.

You must first clarify that which remains pending.

Answer (score 0):

This is a grammatically incorrect sentence; and like JCG mentioned, it makes no sense. Seems like direct translation from the native tongue.

You may be trying to convey the following, 
"Hi, I sent a 'request for budget approval' Email yesterday. this is yet to be approved by you."

It is best to avoid blaming on Emails unless it is absolutely necessary. Hence, I have refrained from using 'did not receive a response'.

Hope it helps.